# how can i use variable in jq?(MacOS,shell)

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I got a Json string as:

```
{
  "id": 3397,
  "title": "title_1"
}
{
  "id": 3396,
  "title": "title_2"
}
```

what I want to do is get every `id` in a loop,
I use the following code :

```
for (( i = 0; i < requestCount; i++ )); do
      requestId=$(echo $jsonString[$i] | jq '.id')
      echo requestId;
done
```

but it doesn't work, I think the way I use variable is wrong, I can't find anything useful here [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

Comment: It's not clear what form of input you have. Is `jsonString` an actual shell array, with one JSON element per object? `jq` can already iterate by itself, so if you had a proper JSON array such as `[ { ...}, {...}]`, you would simply use something like `echo "$json" | jq '.id'`.

Comment: you are right if I wanna to output all id simply. But i need use every id in next command in this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let jq do the iterating. (That is, let jq do the iterating through the input stream of JSON objects.)  For example:

```
$ jq .id <<< "$json" | while read id ; do echo "hello $id"; done
```

Output:

```
hello 3397
hello 3396
```

This way, you don't have to know how many JSON objects are in the input. You might want to use "read -r", or "IFS= read -r".

The alternatives are ugly and inefficient, e.g.:

```
$ for ((i=0;i<2;i++)) ; do jq -s --argjson i "$i" '.[$i].id' <<< "$json" ; done
```

Comment: it worked.i use this :echo $requestJsonbyDate | jq '.[].id' | while read id ; do
 echo "hello $id"; 
done